# Count the childs of a specific node in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml and i need to count all the accounts inside 'User'. I tried several things but all i get is the value for all accounts in xml. I need something like User[1]/Accounts and get the accounts only for that user.

```
<UserList>
 <User>
  <Username>hello</Username>
  <Pin>640</Pin>
  <Accounts>
   <AccountName>Dolar</AccountName>
   <Balance>150</Balance>
   <MaxWithdrawAmount>1200</MaxWithdrawAmount>
   <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
  </Accounts>
  <Accounts>
   <AccountName>RON</AccountName>
   <Balance>650</Balance>
   <MaxWithdrawAmount>5000</MaxWithdrawAmount>
   <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
  </Accounts>
 </User>
 <User>
  <Username>Kevin</Username>
  <Pin>1234</Pin>
  <Accounts>
   <AccountName>RON</AccountName>
   <Balance>650</Balance>
   <MaxWithdrawAmount>5000</MaxWithdrawAmount>
   <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
  </Accounts>
  <Accounts>
   <AccountName>Lei</AccountName>
   <Balance>950</Balance>
   <MaxWithdrawAmount>1200</MaxWithdrawAmount>
   <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
  </Accounts>
 </User>
</UserList>
```

So my output should be:

"For User 1, you have 2 Accounts"
"For User x, you have x Accounts"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using a dictionary with linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENANE = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENANE);

            Dictionary<string, User> dict = doc.Descendants("User").Select(x => new User()
            {
                username = (string)x.Element("Username"),
                pin = (int)x.Element("Pin"),
                accounts = x.Elements("Accounts").ToList()
            }).GroupBy(x => x.username, y => y)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            foreach (var user in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User : {0}, Count = {1}", user.Key, user.Value.accounts.Count());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
                
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public int pin { get; set; }
        public List<XElement> accounts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get this done.

Please read the comments inside the code.

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string XML_String = @"<UserList>
                  <User>
                    <Username>hello</Username>
                    <Pin>640</Pin>
                    <Accounts>
                      <AccountName>Dolar</AccountName>
                      <Balance>150</Balance>
                      <MaxWithdrawAmount>1200</MaxWithdrawAmount>
                      <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
                    </Accounts>
                    <Accounts>
                      <AccountName>RON</AccountName>
                      <Balance>650</Balance>
                      <MaxWithdrawAmount>5000</MaxWithdrawAmount>
                      <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
                    </Accounts>
                  </User>
                  <User>
                    <Username>Kevin</Username>
                    <Pin>1234</Pin>
                    <Accounts>
                      <AccountName>RON</AccountName>
                      <Balance>650</Balance>
                      <MaxWithdrawAmount>5000</MaxWithdrawAmount>
                      <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
                    </Accounts>
                    <Accounts>
                      <AccountName>Lei</AccountName>
                      <Balance>950</Balance>
                      <MaxWithdrawAmount>1200</MaxWithdrawAmount>
                      <MaxDepositAmount>2000</MaxDepositAmount>
                    </Accounts>
                  </User>
                </UserList>";

            var users = GetUsers(XML_String);

            // show in console
            foreach (MyUser usr in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(usr);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<MyUser> GetUsers(string xmlstring)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);
            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("User");

            // List to hold data
            List<MyUser> MyUsersList = new List<MyUser>();
            // Couter for the UserOrderNumber by his order in the document
            int userOrderCounter = 0;
            // Counter for number of accounts
            int accountCounter = 0;

            // iterate over all <User> nodes
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                accountCounter = 0;
                userOrderCounter++;
               
                // create user object 
                MyUser usr = new MyUser();

                // Iterate over all child nodes
                for (int i = 0; i < node.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "Username")
                    {
                        usr.Username = node.ChildNodes[i].InnerXml;
                    }
                    else if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "Pin")
                    {
                        usr.Pin = Convert.ToInt32(node.ChildNodes[i].InnerXml);
                    }
                    else if (node.ChildNodes[i].Name == "Accounts")
                    {
                        accountCounter++;
                    }
                }

                // Add the counters values
                usr.UserOrderNumber = userOrderCounter;
                usr.NumberOfAccountes = accountCounter;
                // Add to list
                MyUsersList.Add(usr);
            }

            return MyUsersList;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// class to hold users retrived from XML document
    /// </summary>
    class MyUser
    {
        public int UserOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public int Pin { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfAccountes { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return return "User " + UserOrderNumber.ToString() + " (Name " + Username + ")" + " Have " + NumberOfAccountes.ToString() + " Accounts";
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

*User 1 (Name hello) Have 2 Accounts

User 2 (Name Kevin) Have 2 Accounts*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using LINQ to XML (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview)

You can find below a snipet:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var userNumber = 0;

foreach (var user in xmlDoc.Element("UserList").Elements("User"))
{
    userNumber++;

    var accounts = user.Elements("Accounts").Count();
    Console.WriteLine($"For User {userNumber}, you have {accounts} Accounts");
}
```

Don't forget to add the required usings:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

and to add a reference to **System.Xml.XDocument.dll** if using .Net Core or **System.Xml.Linq.dll** for .Net Framework